# How I can Create dynamic columns in reporting services?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I need to create report using reporting services to view questions and answers each questions have dynamic answers like below

```
1.Former Australian captain Mark Taylor has had several nicknames over his playing career. Which of the following was NOT one of them?

A.Tubby B.Stodge  C.Helium Bat  D.Stumpy


2.Which was the 1st non Test playing country to beat India in an international match?

A.Canada    B.Sri Lanka  C.Zimbabwe

3.are you married?

A.Yes B.NO
```

Comment: What is you data strtucture? How do questions and asnwers are stored?

Comment: I have two tables first table to save questions and second table to save answers
tbl_questions 


questionID    Description 




tbl_answers


answerID questionID    Description

Comment: Can i do it? @ Yuriy Galanter

Answer (score 0):

You do not need dynamic columns. Just create a query that JOINs questions and answers and in SSRS group by question, displaying answers in details.